# Add button in jqgrid to the extreme right end of toppager

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to add one div at the end of toppager in jqGrid.  Below link explains how to add button in toppager_right.

http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/how-to-add-custom-button-to-toppager_right-or-toppager_center

Below is my code:

`$("#grid_toppager_right").html('<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="float: right; table-layout: auto;" class="ui-pg-table navtable"><tbody><tr><td style="width: 4px;" ><div>abc1234</div></td></tr></tbody></table>');`

It adds abc1234 to the left of toppager_right. Can someone please help me how I can position it to the extreme right end of toppager?

Comment: show some snippets of code and samples of what you have tried... give something from which to work with

Comment: Thanks Dave, I have edited the question...

Comment: try changing `border="0"` to `border="1"` to check and ensure that it isn't your table, but your span that isn't aligned correctly.  Guessing it could be the table style is being overwritten.

Comment: the workaround referenced was from over a year ago.  possible the behavior has changed since making it no longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

I could finally position the div towards right. Here is the explanation for the same.
grid_toppager consists of table with class ".ui-pg-table.ui-common-table.ui-pager-table". It has 3 td elements named grid_toppager_left, grid_toppager_center, grid_toppager_right. I gave width = 100% for the table and that's it, I achieved what I wanted:

```
.ui-pg-table.ui-common-table.ui-pager-table {
    width: 100%;
}
```

By default, toppager_right is aligned to right as below

```
 <td align="right" id="jqCCGrid_toppager_right">
 </td>
```

So, whatever I add inside above td gets added at the right end of toppager.